# How to test Spring Cloud Stream Listener

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, mockmvc

I have a controller calling service with following methods:

```
Something send(SomeMessage message) {
    binding.sendSomeMessage().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
}

@StreamListener(target = "SomeInput")
void listen(SomeResponse response) {
    // do something...
}
```

Now, I need to test it. I have a test for my controller simply using `mockMvc`. It calls an endpoint, than this service and sends my message to a defined queue. I need to be able call something to be able to simulate response to trigger that listener.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are new to spring-cloud-stream and using an old soon to be deprecated way of configuring message listeners. We have longed switched to function based model and you can find the details and examples on how to test [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_testing). 
As you will see the same testing approach will work for legacy `StreamListeners` and here is [one of our tests](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/tck/ContentTypeTckTests.java) that will show you how to do that.
However, I would recommend switching to functional model. It's simpler, less code and less configuration.